# Apache Pig - Numeric data missing while loading in a pig relation

Tags: apache-pig

I am learning Apache Pig. I am trying to load some data in to pig. When i see the txt file in vi editor, I find the following (sample) row.

> [ABBOTT,DEEDEE W GRADES 9-12 TEACHER     52,122.10       0       LBOE 
>   ATLANTA INDEPENDENT SCHOOL SYSTEM       2010].

I use the following command to load data into a pig relation.

```
A = LOAD 'salaryTravelReport_sample.txt' USING PigStorage() as (name:chararray,
prof:chararray,max_sal:float,travel:float,board:chararray,state:chararray,year:int);
```

However, when I do a dump in pig in the distributed environment, I find the following result (for the row mentioned above):

> (ABBOTT,DEEDEE W,GRADES 9-12 TEACHER,,0.0,LBOE,ATLANTA INDEPENDENT
>   SCHOOL SYSTEM,2010).

The numeric data `"52,122.10       "` seems to be missing.

Please help.

Comment: whats the file separator ? Is it tab ?

Comment: Yes Murali , it is tab separated.

Comment: try loading with PigStorage('\t')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PigStorage() is inbuilt function in pig which takes record delimiter as arguments. here its tab --  > \t

```
A = LOAD 'salaryTravelReport_sample.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (name:chararray,
prof:chararray,max_sal:float,travel:float,board:chararray,state:chararray,year:int);
```

Comment: @Nemichandra : you can accept this answer if it helped.